# Generate running combinations of vector values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

What I need to achieve is basically a list of all combinations of vector values but running trough windows of a given length. It's more easier to show than to explain.

Let say I have a `window.size` of `3`

```
vector <- c("goofy", "mickey", "donald", "foo", "bar")
```

This is what I need as output

```
from  |  to
------+-----
goofy | mickey
goofy | donald
mickey| donald
mickey| foo
donald| bar
donald| foo
foo   | bar
```

As this is going to end in a monte carlo set of iterations, `windows.size` should be parametric

I think it could be easily done with dplyr and tidyr but I was not able to figure out how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't there be also a `donald` `foo` combination?

Comment: It sounds like this is essentially the base of what you want: `expand.grid(vector[1:3], vector[1:3])`, then it just needs to be extended to a rolling window.

Comment: added donald foo combination, thanks for pointing me out the missing :)

Answer (score 5):

With `rollapply` and `dplyr`. The `c`, `do.call`, `as.data.frame` ugliness are needed to convert the output of `combn` to a dataframe for `dplyr` functions:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

rollapply(vector, 3, combn, 2, simplify = FALSE) %>%
  c() %>%
  do.call(rbind, .) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  distinct() %>%
  setNames(c("from", "to"))
```

**Result:**

```
    from     to
1  goofy mickey
2 mickey donald
3 donald    foo
4  goofy donald
5 mickey    foo
6 donald    bar
7    foo    bar
```

Comment: Nice use of `rollapply`. Minor suggestion: replace `group_by_all() %>% slice(1)` with `distinct()`.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov Thanks. I totally forgot `distinct`

Comment: Here is another vaiation: `rollapply(vector, 3, combn, 2, toString) %>% c %>% unique %>% read.csv(text = ., header = FALSE, as.is = TRUE, col.names = c("from", "to"))`

Answer (score 2):

You could play around with the indices logic and the subsetting to make a generalisable form of:

```
data.frame(
  from = vector[c(rep(1:3, each = 2), 4)],
  to = vector[c(2, rep(3:5, each = 2))]
)

    from     to
1  goofy mickey
2  goofy donald
3 mickey donald
4 mickey    foo
5 donald    foo
6 donald    bar
7    foo    bar
```

Where the original `vector` is: `c("goofy", "mickey", "donald", "foo", "bar")`.

**EDIT**

A bit more gerneralisable:

```
n <- length(vector)
data.frame(
  from = vector[rep(1:(n-1), each = 2)[-2*n + 2]],
  to = vector[rep(2:n, each = 2)[-1]]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lead` from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
## Example of n = 2
n = 2
res = data.frame()
for(i in 1:n){res = na.omit(rbind(res,cbind(v,lead(v,i))))}
names(res) = c("from","to")
res
    from     to
1  goofy mickey
2 mickey donald
3 donald    foo
4    foo    bar
5  goofy donald
6 mickey    foo
7 donald    bar

## Example of n = 4
n = 4
res = data.frame()
for(i in 1:n){res = na.omit(rbind(res,cbind(v,lead(v,i))))}
names(res) = c("from","to")
res
     from     to
1   goofy mickey
2  mickey donald
3  donald    foo
4     foo    bar
5   goofy donald
6  mickey    foo
7  donald    bar
8   goofy    foo
9  mickey    bar
10  goofy    bar
```